# Jordan form and basis for 5 x 5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> [image: Part c]
>
> [image]

Is anybody able to explain the solution to part c of this question above? I don't understand how the characteristic polynomial was determined, or how the basis was found.

Comment: The picture is hardly readable. I think this solution is cheating because, when asked to calculate characteristic polynomial, nobody would ever try calculating $A^3$ first. My advice is don't read this solution. Instead go through the general algorithm of Jordan normal form computation.

Comment: @WhatsUp How does $A^3=0$ determine the characteristic polynomial? Also the general algorithm gets very messy with this matrix, so I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: $A^3 =0$ means the characteristic polynomial divides $x^3$, and $A^2 \neq0 $ means the characteristic polynomial does not divide $x^2$.

Comment: In general computations with matrices of size $5$ or larger are indeed messy to do with hands. That's why we need computers. But at educational level one should probably do some examples by hand to understand the method.

Comment: Do you mean $x^3$ divides the characteristic polynomial? Also where did the negative come from in the characteristic polynomial? I think the point of the question is that it can be done without using a computer, I just don't understand the tricks used.

Comment: Sorry, I meant minimal polynomial above. Since the characteristic polynomial has same roots as the minimal polynomial, it must be $x^5$. The minus is irrelevant: some people define characteristic polynomial as $\det(A- x I)$ while others define it as $\det (xI-A)$. The difference is simply a sign.

Comment: Do you know how the basis vectors were found? I'm not familiar at all with the method used above.

Comment: @WhatsUp It’s not at all unreasonable to examine powers of the matrix here since it’s traceless, hence nilpotent. We therefore already know its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @amd But traceless only says that the sum of eigenvalues is zero, not that it's nilpotent. E.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Its determinant is also obviously zero.

Comment: @amd Even then it only says that sum of eigenvalues is zero and product of eigenvalues is zero. E.g. $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\1& 0 & 0\\0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Fair enough. The two observations enough to suspect a nilpotent matrix in an articificial exercise, at any rate, so my initial comment stands: it’s not unreasonable to examine powers of this matrix before grinding through generic methods. Not sure that really saves much work overall, though.

Comment: @amd Imagine there are five complex numbers. You know that their sum and product are zero. And you guess "are they all zero?" and the guess costs you some time (doing two matrix multiplications) while there are methods that guarantee to find the answer in not so much more time. If the guess fails then you don't get anything...

Comment: @WhatsUp You know a lot more than that in this case. It’s quite easy to see by inspection that at least three of those numbers are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from examining simple linear combinations of $A$’s columns, we can quickly see that its rank is at most two. In addition, its first two rows are obviously linearly independent, hence its rank is exactly two. So, we know that it has zero as an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $3$, and therefore that $x^3$ divides its characteristic polynomial.

Since the matrix is also traceless, instead of computing the characteristic polynomial directly as $\det(\lambda I-A)$, the solution makes a leap of faith (or uses insider knowledge) and guesses that $A$ might be nilpotent. Since we know that the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is three, this only requires checking at most $A^2$ and $A^3$. I’m not sure that this really saves that much work over the general method, though. As we see in the solution, $A^2\ne0$ but $A^3=0$, so the matrix is indeed nilpotent. Nilpotent matrices only have $0$ as an eigenvalue, which gives us the characteristic polynomial $x^5$, with minimal polynomial $x^3$. It looks like this text uses $\det(A-\lambda I)$ instead of $\det(\lambda I-A)$, which is why the book solution has $(-x)^5$ instead. The latter equivalent definition guarantees a monic polynomial for any order matrix.

The solution proceeds conventionally from there. There’s only one nontrivial Jordan block, so a simple-looking vector that’s not in $\ker(A^2)$ is chosen to start the chain. After that, the remaining two basis vectors are found by inspection. The first two columns of $A$ are equal, so $\mathbf e_1-\mathbf e_2$ is a null vector of $A$, as is $\mathbf e_5$ because the last column is zero. You should verify that the three vectors in the Jordan chain together with these two are linearly independent.